# React Native: Props Change Causes Touch Event to Cancel

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm using the `react-native-gesture-handler` library to create a drag-and-drop sortable array of components. I'm at the point now that I'm starting to work on adding animations to it. I do this by using `LayoutAnimations.configureNext(Constants.MyAnimConfig)` in select places where I wish to animate the next change(s).

The array of data itself (`data`), along with a basic render function (`renderItem({item, index})`, as well as a function to be called when the data array is reordered (`onReorder: (nextData: Array<any>) => void`, a function that overwrites the previous array with the new one), are passed as props to the list component.

I use state to keep track of the touch point and the elements of the list. Each element is the same size, and with the same margin. This means that every time the touch XY change, I use a function to calculate the index that the touch event is hovering over, and then I re-order the array, and pass the new array to the `onReorder` prop.

I began to get frustrated because everything was animating nicely, except for the array re-ordering. That is, until I realized that I was using the `index` as the key for each element in the array. React never noticed that the list was being re-ordered because of that. So, I changed the key to a value that was unique per element in the array, and *viola!* it started animating the change!

There was one major problem though... the touch event started getting cancelled when the array was re-ordered. Even weirder, it was only when elements were moved *down* the list. Moving them up the list seemed to work just fine...

I have a feeling that this may be due to the change in props? I was thinking of creating an array of `data` in the list's own state and then render/reorder that instead and simply use a `useEffect()` block to keep the state up--to-date. However, is that really the best method?

I will post code if you would like, however there really isn't anything special going on here.

**Full Code For List Component:** https://gist.github.com/baughmann/82923c1c70390ab87ebfd7900354a2f3

**EDIT:**
It seems my guess that it was caused by updating props (and thus, triggering a re-render) was incorrect. Even when in local state cancels the touch. Next step is to try to throw it into a reducer function outside the scope of the component and cross my fingers....

**EDIT 2:** Moving the `data` array into a reducer also did not work. At this point, I only have one guess. My list component wraps the `renderItem` props in it's own `_renderItem` function that wraps the list item inside a `PanGestureHandler` like so:

```
const _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    const isBeingDragged = isMoving && index === dragIndex;

    const style: ViewStyle = {
      width: itemStyle.width,
      height: itemStyle.width,
      opacity: isBeingDragged ? 0 : 1,
    };

    return (
      <PanGestureHandler
        key={`handler-${item.name}`}
        onGestureEvent={e => onMove(e, index)}
        onHandlerStateChange={e => onState(e, index)}>
        <Animated.View style={{...itemStyle, ...style}}>
          {renderItem({item, index})}
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    );
  };
```

My assumption now is that the event gets cancelled because the `PanGestureHandler` that triggered and was continuing the touch event was re-rendered due to the array re-ordering. As to why this only happens when elements move down the list is anyone's guess. At this point, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So indeed I was onto something with the last edit. The re-rendering of the `<PanGestureHandler />` that was handling the pan movement was cancelling the gesture. This is because I had included one `<PanGestureHandler />` *per* rendered item in the list. While this was a convenient way to get the index of the element that was being dragged by the user and pass it to the `onGestureEvent` and `onHandlerStateChange` event handlers, it ultimately had to go.

What I should have done from the beginning was render only one `<PanGestureHandler />` and place it above the list, and then use the function I created to get the index of an element in the array based on an XY coordinate to get the index instead. That is ultimately what I did:

```
  <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onMove} onHandlerStateChange={onState}>
    <View
      onLayout={({nativeEvent: {layout}}) => setContainerView(layout)}
      style={styles.listContainer}>
      {data.map((item, index) => _renderItem({item, index}))}
    </View>
  </PanGestureHandler>
```

If you're facing a similar issue, you should check out the gist I created [here](https://gist.github.com/baughmann/82923c1c70390ab87ebfd7900354a2f3). Just keep in mind that this list was created to be **horizontal** which probably differs from your own implementation. It also *does* need some changing. Plan accordingly.